# Global JavaScript variable not accessible in jQuery change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables, scope

I have to be missing something simple, but I'm really not sure what.

I have a button that, when clicked, gets JSON data.  When a drop-down is changed, I check to see if there is data, if there is, I want to clear it out as the drop-down indicates what data to retrieve when the button is clicked

The Code:

```
 var selected, $locDialog;
 var locations = [];

$(function() {
// Save the selected Name
selected = $("#selected option:selected").val();

// Setup Dialog for Locations
$locDialog = $('#location-dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false
});

// If user changes the selected
// 1.  Prompt for confirmation
// 2.  If users confirms, clear  data
$('#selected').change(function() {
    if (locations) {
        var confirmed = confirm("Oh Rly?");
        if (confirmed) {
            // Clear data
            var locations;
        }
    }
});

// When user clicks "Location" Button..
$('.loc-select button').click(function() {
    if (!locations) {
        $.getJSON("/Controller/JSONAction", { selectedId: selected, pageNum: 1, pageSize: 100 }, function(data) {
            locations = data;
            $.each(locations, function(index, loc) {
                var $tr = $('<tr/>')
                    .append($('<td/>')
                        .append('<input type="checkbox" name="TEST-'+index+'" value="'+loc.Id+'"/>'))
                    .append('<td>' + loc.Name + '</td>');
                $("#location-dialog table tbody").append($tr);
            });
        });
    }
    $locDialog.dialog('open');
    return false;
});
});
```

Here's the thing, Inside the `.click(...)` callback, I can see `locations` is `[]`.  Now, when I am in the `.change(...)` callback, I see `locations` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing this line...

```
// Clear data
var locations;
```

to this...

```
// Clear data
locations = [];
```

Here's what's happening:  you're declaring a new 'locations' variable which is covering the  global one.  In JavaScript, any variables declared in the function are visible throughout the function -- even if they're declared in (what looks to you like) a nested scope.

Comment: Thanks Drew :).  Question:  var locations inside the callback isn't executed right away, is it?  I guess that is why I never thought to change that.  I knew it was something simple though!